# How to stop my WCF server readline thread?

Tags: multithreading, wcf, readline

recently I implemented a pipe server which can be connected by multi clients. there is a readline function in the server thread to keep reading the messages sent from the connected client. When the application closing, the pipe server thread should safely exited. However, things is not happening as I expected, the server realine() can not be aborted by the thread.abort().

Here is my implemention:

```
    private string TryReadLine(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        int TimeOutCount = 0;
        var thread = new Thread(readerThread);
        thread.Start();
        Get.Set();
        Got.Reset();
        while (!Got.WaitOne(ServerWaitReadMillisecs))//for just 1s
        {
            //check if the task has been cancelled
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                thread.Abort();//stop the pipe reading thread
                Log.Info($"Pipe{ID} task will be cancelled");
                throw new PipeServerTaskCancelled();
            }

            TimeOutCount++;
            if (TimeOutCount > MaxTimeout)
            {
                thread.Abort();//stop the pipe reading thread
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
            Log.Info($"this is the {TimeOutCount} time pipe read timeout for Pipe{ID}");
        }
        return inputContext;
    }

    private void readerThread()
    {
        Get.WaitOne();
        inputContext = sr.ReadLine();//read message from the pipe(originally sent from the wcf service)
        Got.Set();
    }
```

Comment: sorry for confusion, this is not for WCF readline, it is for named pipe readline, the [sr] in the code is intialized with pipe connectted, like sr = new StreamReader(Server);

Comment: 1) Stream.ReadTimeout not supported for NamedPipeServerStream
2) Abort() or Interupt() doesn't work on thread
3) NamedPipeServerStream.Disconnect() nether work